# create envelope from mesh in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to add a picture containing a square to my project in Illustrator. The square in the picture is slightly warped, and I would like to align it to my artboard.

I can use a envelope with a n x n mesh, but then the mesh does not align to the square. So, I created a mesh of size equal to the image, where 4 sub mesh-points correspond to the corners of the square. The result I get by applying this mesh using "from top layer" is wrong, as can be seen in the images below (original image from: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chess_set_4o06.jpg).

Is there a way of anchoring the mesh-points in a non-rectangular way?

[image: The mesh]
[image: After applying the top layer as a mesh]

Comment: You should do any raster image correction in Photoshop, then use the image in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

The lines represent isoparameters. That property precludes the possibility of doing this. You need to use some other software for this (there are plenty of those around, for example Maya can do this).

**Edity**: Okay, you could first manipulate the image by reverse values and then envelope it but that's just way too far into i dont want to go there territory, besides its destructive on image quality. T-1 * A *T if you may.